# Goldbach Conjecture Consequences

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, goldbachs-conjecture

I have been looking into the Goldbach Conjecture pretty recently and I have often heard that it would have far-reaching consequences. However, I haven't found many of the actual consequences.  I was wondering if you all could supply me with some of these consequences (theorems, etc.).

Comment: Assume someone proved or disproved the Goldbach conjecture. Main consequence: Everybody who has used the Goldbach conjecture as an example of a presumed undecidable statement would have to edit their work.

Comment: "I have often heard that it would have far-reaching consequences." I have never heard this. Can you cite an example? What I have heard is that any proof would almost certainly require some technical breakthrough that might help with other problems like the ABC conjecture.

Comment: Just like the abc-conjecture / theorem, Fermat's last theorem and Szemerédi's theorem, a proof of the Goldbach conjecture is likely to contain heaps of new and probably interesting theory.

Comment: But this is a possible consequence of the proof. What, if any, are the consequences of the theorem itself?

Comment: As with Fermat's Last Theorem, the statement of Goldbach's conjecture on its own (not any potential proof) doesn't have amazing consequences. The problem is famous because it is old and elementary to state. Perhaps you misunderstood what was meant when you heard it would have great consequences, or whoever made this claim was misinformed. Where did you hear such a remark (often)?

Comment: Conveniently, the [weak Goldbach conjecture has now been proven](http://www.truthiscool.com/prime-numbers-the-271-year-old-puzzle-resolved).

Comment: The main consequence would be non-existence of counterexample of Goldbach conjecture.

If such counterexample exists, it would be astonishing since it is 'against' all the statistics. I would be sad to know that there would be no such amazing 'Goldbach number'.